# How to constrain range using beego orm

Tags: database, go, orm, beego

I would like to constrain an attribute to a certain range using beego orm, similar to

```
CHECK(“column” >= 0 AND “column” <= 10)
```

in the table setup. Can I do this with beego, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

The command doesn't seem to give any options for inserting CHECK, it's quite an esoteric SQL command, and there is no hint of it in the [source](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/astaxie/beego@522b3a4a70bd86c20e5d2f4ca6320b44204c0019/-/blob/orm/cmd_utils.go#L135:6) at getDbCreateSQL or the [docs](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md).

I suggest you just create your tables with SQL instead and insert the sql you have above, this should be a one-time task so not too onerous.